# How to combine these two function (scheme)?

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to combine following code into one:

```
   (define (foundList x)
        (when (pair? x)
         ((hash-ref *function-table* (car x)) (cdr x))))

(define (endofstring x)
  (if (not (null?(cdr x)))
    (endofstring (cdr x))
    (foundList (car x))))
```

I tried to do following but i get "hash-ref: no value found for key"

```
(define (endofstring x)
  (if (not (null?(cdr x)))
    (endofstring (cdr x))
    (if (when (pair? x) 
      ((hash-ref *function-table* (car x)) (cdr x)))
      (car x) (void))))
```

Need Help thanx

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing `x` in `endofstring` with `x` in `foundList`.

Replace `(foundList (car x))` with the body of `foundList`, where you've replaced `x` with `(car x)`.
That is, with

```
(when (pair? (car x))
    ((hash-ref *function-table* (car (car x))) (cdr (car x))))
```

and you get

```
(define (endofstring x)
  (if (not (null?(cdr x)))
    (endofstring (cdr x))
    (when (pair? (car x))
        ((hash-ref *function-table* (car (car x))) (cdr (car x))))))
```

Comment: it didn't work ...I got following result ...."when: bad syntax
  in: (when (pair? (car x) ((hash-ref *fun-table* (car (car x))) (cdr (car x)))))"

Comment: @mike123 Bad parentheses. Fixed now.